# how to open the locked pdf page (server Url )in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

> I want to show the Pdf in the View By url the pdf is locked.

```
struct PDFKitV : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var url: URL?
    var document: PDFDocument?
    init(url: URL){
        self.url = url
    }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        var pdfView = PDFView()

        if let url = url {
            pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url)
//            pdfView.document?.delegate = context.coordinator
            pdfView.document?.unlock(withPassword: "alib_3")
        }
        return pdfView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        // Empty
    }
    
}
```

> this is the main view here I want to show the pdf

```
struct Pdf: View{

@State var currentPage: Int = 1
@State var totalPage: Int = 1

@StateObject var list = PreviewBooksViewModel()
var body: some View{// print("\(self.path)/\(self.currentPage).pdf")
    VStack{
        PDFKitV(url: ((URL(string: "\(list.pageUrl)"))!))
    }.onAppear{
        list.getBookData()
    }
}
}
```

> I am printing the url and it prints correctly but I don't understand

> when I try to fetch By url then show very nice but when  I am calling
> the Api then it shows nothing.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The code you have shown above successfully opens a password protected PDF. Where is the "next button", and what does it do?  Please give a minimal example that reproduces the problem, ideally for SwiftUI as `struct ContentView` people can paste into Xcode and run. Take a look at [mcve]

Comment: The problem is that when I try to load pdf page from API then it is showing blank page but whenever we copied the url and paste in pdfkit url section then shows properly where I am wrong.

Comment: Please show the exact code that is failing, that can be run by someone trying to solve your problem. If necessary create a new single view app project to demonstrate it.

Comment: How can anyone run this code? What is, for example, `AuthenticationPreviewBookService`? Again, please show the exact code that is failing, _that can be run by someone trying to solve your problem_. Please read [mcve]

Comment: `AuthenticationPreviewBookService` this is the class where authenticate the user by JWT tokens. and I edited again My question @AshleyMills I am new in swift.

Comment: Ok. This _still_ doesn't run as is. I fixed it by adding a `NetworkError` enum, but please stop making people do work for you. Anyway, after adding that code, it works fine - a PDF about dogs is displayed.

Comment: There's no way I can test this code without a JWT. **Once again**, please add a [mcve]

Comment: @AshleyMills please look again my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**>Try this Snipped**

```
struct PDFKitV: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = PDFView
    let url: URL
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PDFView {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
        pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
        
        return pdfView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PDFView, context: Context) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            if let document = PDFDocument(url: url) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    uiView.document = document
                    document.unlock(withPassword: "alib_3")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be working, but as requested there is no minimal working code. here the working code is `loop (count) do curl -O URL\count.pdf & count.pdf`

I suggest you merge those pages as otherwise its 37 tabs to read the book without needing the password, as its stored in this viewers cache for each tab to use.

[image]
[image]

the core issue is a PDF applies the password at opening so the view command is where the password needs to be applied.

In my **C**all**URL** the password is NOT needed.

let aURL = //any pdf url
let document = PDFDocument(url: aURL)

**It IS needed to be stored and applied in the viewer.**

let password = "alib_3"
document?.unlock(withPassword: password)
pdfView.document = document